# prototype function missing when calling third party node package in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use a third party Node module in an angular 2+ project.

installed with `npm install --save ModuleName`

The function in question is in a file named Foo.js and looks like this:

```
var foo = function(param1, param2) {
    ...
    this.init();
}

foo.protoype = {
    constructor: foo,

    init: function(){
        ...
    },
    ...
}

module.exports = foo;
```

index.js for the node module looks like:

```
var ModuleName = require("./src/ModuleName");
ModuleName.foo = require("./src/Foo");

module.exports = ModuleName;
```

I am trying to use the module in a Directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleName } from "ModuleName"

@Directive({
  selector: '[customDirective]'
})
export class CustomDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let poorlyNamedVariable = ModuleName.foo(param1, param2);
  }
}
```

When foo is called it produces `ERROR TypeError: this.init is not a function`

`console.log(this)` in foo shows an instance of ModuleName which, in turn, has an instance of `foo`, which has a prototype where `init` is defined.

I suspect the problem stems from some sort of scoping issue, but am still too new to both Angular and Node to untangle the mess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import * as ModuleName from "ModuleName"` for CommonJS modules.

Comment: Same result. `this.init is not a function`.

Comment: @Lunchbox Which module are you trying to use? It might be a bug

Comment: @Lunchbox `import ModuleName = require("ModuleName")` might solve this. Please let me know if it worked.